# Why Sqlite return only last row not all rows data?

Tags: android, sqlite

I don't know what's wrong with my code I follow the rule but I get wrong result. I want to search db and find all rows data but I only get last row from sqlite. my code to search database is bellow:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<ContractSaveDataFromDB>> ActiveContractData(String phone, String numberId)
{
    ArrayList<ContractSaveDataFromDB> UserData = new ArrayList<ContractSaveDataFromDB>();

    ArrayList<ArrayList<ContractSaveDataFromDB>> SendUserData =
            new ArrayList<ArrayList<ContractSaveDataFromDB>>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String whereClause = "phone = ? AND numberId = ?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[]{
            phone,
            numberId
    };

    String orderBy = "activeContract";
    Cursor res2=db.query("usersAccount",null,whereClause,whereArgs,null,null,orderBy);

    res2.moveToFirst();

       do{
           UserData.clear();
           int index;

           ContractSaveDataFromDB contractSaveDataFromDB=new ContractSaveDataFromDB();

               index = res2.getColumnIndex("buyAmount");
               String buyAmount = res2.getString(index);
               contractSaveDataFromDB.setBuyAmount(buyAmount);

               UserData.add(contractSaveDataFromDB);
               SendUserData.add(UserData);

         } while(res2.moveToNext());

    res2.close();
    db.close();

    return SendUserData;
```

I don't know what's wrong. I appreciate if you help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Do you, in fact, have multiple rows that match your query in the database? What are the type affinities of your phone and numberId columns? If you're storing integers in one or both, comparing those values against a string will fail (Try it yourself: `SELECT 3 = '3';`)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issues is that you are trying to use an ArrayList of ArrayList of ContractSaveDataFromDB objects.

I believe that an ArrayList of ContractSaveDataFromDB objects would suffice.

It would also help you if you learnt to do a bit of basic debugging, as an issue could be that you are not extracting multiple rows.

The following is an alternative method that :-

- uses the ArrayList of ContractSaveDataFromDB objects,
- introduces some debugging by the way of writing some potentially useful information to the log
- and is more sound, as it will not crash if no rows are extracted

  - i.e. if you use `moveToFirst` and don't check the result (false means the move could not be accomplished) then you would get an error because you are trying to read row -1 (before the first row) as no rows exists in the cursor.

:-

```
public ArrayList<ContractSaveDataFromDB> ActiveContractData(String phone, String numberId) {
    ArrayList<ContractSaveDataFromDB> SendUserData = new ArrayList<ContractSaveDataFromDB>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String whereClause = "phone = ? AND numberId = ?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[]{
            phone,
            numberId
    };

    String orderBy = "activeContract";
    Cursor res2 = db.query("usersAccount", null, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, orderBy);
    Log.d("RES2 COUNT", "Number of rows in Res2 Cursor is " + String.valueOf(res2.getCount()));

    while (res2.moveToNext()) {
        ContractSaveDataFromDB current_user_data = new ContractSaveDataFromDB();
        current_user_data.setBuyAmount(res2.getString(res2.getColumnIndex("buyAmount")));
        Log.d("NEWROW", "Adding data from row " + String.valueOf(res2.getPosition()));
        SendUserData.add(current_user_data);
    }
    res2.close();
    db.close();
    Log.d("EXTRACTED", "The number of rows from which data was extracted was " + String.valueOf(SendUserData.size()));
    return SendUserData;
}
```

- If after running you check the log you should see :-

  - A line detailing how many rows were extracted from the table
  - A line for each row (**if any were extracted**) saying **Adding data from row ?** (where ? will be the row 0 being the first)
  - A line saying **The number of rows from which data was extracted was ?** (? will be the number of elements in the array to be returned)

Comment: Again It does not work for me and I only access to last row. I don't know why

Comment: @seyyedhamidshojaedin Answer has been amended.

Answer (score 0):

you already added where clause so maybe it is filtering your results try to remove it by change this

```
Cursor res2=db.query("usersAccount",null,whereClause,whereArgs,null,null,orderBy);
```

to this

```
Cursor res2=db.query("usersAccount",null,null,null,null,null,orderBy);
```

Comment: But I want to search and find specific rows not all table rows